# A Multi-layer .NET framework based on POCO

Tags: .net, entity-framework, architecture, poco, devforce

I'm developing a framework and need samples and a best practices to have better performance and code less.
I wonder if there is an open source enterprise project using POCO for Web Applications covering most of topics mentioned in [Application Architecture Guide ver 2](http://apparchguide.codeplex.com/) such as:

- Authentication
- Authorization
- Caching
- Communication between layers
- Exception Management
- Logging
- Validation
- Transactions
- ...

edit:
Well, Microsoft Enterprise Library implemented the above topics, but it is not a layered enterprise framework. Same for 1Code.
I'm looking for a sample of an enterprise project with UI/[Facade]/BLL/Common/Data Access layers including resource-based authentication, using simple classes as entities.
A loosely coupled multi-layer (ready to multi-tier) sample.

Comment: What application architectural style(s) are you targeting?

Comment: Question updated, if it is not your answer please tell me what do you mean by application architectural style. Thanks

Comment: So you're trying to build a general framework for N-Tier applications?

Comment: Yes. A general framework for N-Tier (or even N-Layer) applications benefiting mentioned concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for the **Microsoft Enterprise Library**? Here's a [start page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx) for the documentation and downloads.

All of your bullet point features are covered by the code in the Enterprise Library. Or, as you suggest, you can use it as samples and best practices.

There is also a huge amount of sample code and best practices in the **All-in-One framework** that starts [here](https://1code.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks DOK, but according the guid (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953191(v=pandp.50).aspx):
Enterprise Library is made up of a series of application blocks, each aimed at managing specific crosscutting concerns.
Application blocks help address the kinds of problems developers commonly face from one line-of-business project to the next.
I'll update my question and give more information about what I'm looking for.

Comment: EntLib is widely used in large enterprises in layered applications.

Comment: Agree. But it is used *in* enterprise layered applications, Is there an enterprise layered application source code available? Of course there are some source codes, but they're using old ADO.NET and not using .NET 4 features. I'm looking for an updated one.

Answer (score 3):

I think the final answer to your question will be very personal.  There are tons of frameworks for many parts of the ecosystem you're looking for, but the thing is that you have to integrate them all by yourself.

There is a commercial solution that will cover a lot of parts of your question : DevForce from Ideablade (here : http:/www.ideablade.com).  It's free for a proof of concept but over (I think) 5 entities you need the real stuff.  It layers over EntityFramework, uses AOP (PostSharp) and WCF, all of which you could integrate by yourself of course.

EDIT : I forgot to mention the DevForce Application Framework, an open-source project by IdeaBlade that extends the features of DevForce.  http://devforcecaliburn.codeplex.com/ which seems to be re-spinned as Cocktail : http://cocktail.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft spain has written a Architecture Guide that can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/architecture/en/

Answer (score 1):

Ayande Rahien (of [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) fame) has a series of blog posts on building such a beast.  I do not believe that he has implemented any actual code, but his discussion is quite interesting.

His introduction can be found at http://ayende.com/blog/4087/macto-or-how-to-build-a-prison, and the entire discussion is tagged [Macto](http://ayende.com/blog/tags/macto) on his [blog](http://ayende.com/blog/).

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Layered Architecture Solution Guidance](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c8c473b5-21a1-447a-8b24-33b43411ee7f) in the Visual Studio Gallery that can aid you in your task.

You can also check this other [Visual Studio extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/444961dc-ee7d-44aa-a076-9cce1b9cdc4d) with a model-first approach.